# angular js showing 500 server error

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I am getting 500 server error while i am writing a code for $http in angularJs. I am using Ubuntu OS

### Code is given below

```
 $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost.com/domain/index.php?r=site/CheckDomain',
        headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ=='},
        data: {urlName: $scope.urlName, domainExt: $scope.domainExt},
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        toaster.pop('success', "Successer", 'Total 7 Result Found', 25000, 'trustedHtml', '');
        //$scope.domainExt = data;
        $scope.results = data.records;
        $scope.showresult = true;
        //Code use to assign default values in price dropdown
        angular.forEach($scope.results, function(value, key) {
            $scope.model[key] = value.selectedOption.dp_id;
        });


    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

    });
```

### Response is given below

Access-Control-Allow-Orig...    http://localhost.com/domain/ 
Connection  close 
Content-Type    text/html
Date    Sun, 14 Sep 2014 06:52:46 GMT
Server  Apache/2.4.7 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1f PHP/5.5.9 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.5.9

Accept  application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Authorization   Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
Content-Length  38
Content-Type    application/json;charset=utf-8
Cookie  KCFINDER_showname=on; KCFINDER_showsize=off; KCFINDER_showtime=off;
 KCFINDER_order=name; KCFINDER_orderDesc=off; KCFINDER_view=thumbs; 
KCFINDER_displaySettings=off
Host    localhost.com

Comment: The data which is returned from server to client has to be in json format. convert data into it. this error will not occur again

Comment: @mironyks
Data is coming in json format only. i am using "json_encode($result);" function. Code is working fine in windows machine, facing issue in Ubuntu OS only

Answer (score 0):

Your request shows

```
Content-Type text/html
```

Change your $http.post to have

```
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ=='}
```

If it still throws server error, look at the server logs for exceptions in the server code

Comment: its 500 internal server error and i am facing it on linux machine only, on Windows machine its working fine

Comment: yes, you need to look at the server logs to figure out the issue. Which server are you running?

Comment: I am using apache server (xampp), also tell me where is server log of apache Server

Comment: I haven't used xampp. Usually logs are stored in /var/log/<app>. Look at that /var/log/<app> and your installation directory. If you don't find it here, read the xampp documentation or google for it providing details of your os.

Comment: Hi Deepak
I checked my error log but nothing found relevant to my problem :( 
Thanks for your suggestions